# Aonde eu acho o Web.Config no ASP.NET CORE MVC 3.1?

Tags: mvc, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8, web.config, asp-net-core

Estou tendo problemas com acentuação em uma View, já abri no bloco de notas as minhas view's em .cshtml e salve todas com UTF-8 porém está com problema de acentuação na aplicação ainda, eu verifiquei em todos as pastas e não encontrei o Web.Config só o appsettings.json :(

Answer (score 1):

Ficou um pouco vago o real erro, mas, talvez a resposta abaixo resolva seu caso.

Acredito que você tenha que criar o `web.config` na mão, o aspnet não tem ele como padrão.
Sobre a pergunta em si, se não há uma cultura globalizada definida, ele irá pegar da máquina e se ela estiver com padrão estrangeiro, terá problemas, talvez.

Em sua view deve ter o seguinte código: `@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`

retire-o.

Isso pode ser resolvido globalizando a configuração da App na classe `Startup` em `configure`:

```
    var defaultCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
    var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
    {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(defaultCulture),
        SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { defaultCulture },
        SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { defaultCulture }
    };
    app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

A App vai instanciar com `pt-BR` como padrão

E na partial `_ValidationScriptPartial`  você pode adicionar um javascript para validar de acordo como usamos por exemplo, separação de milhar e decimal, aqui no Brasil.

sobre o webconfig, veja esta pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186445/access-web-config-settings-in-asp-net-core-app